# Remove all occurrences of a list of words vim

Tags: variables, vim, str-replace

Having a document whose first line is `foo,bar,baz,qux,quux`, is there a way to store these words in a variable as a list `['foo','bar','baz','qux','quux']`and remove all their occurrences in a document with vim?

Like a command `:removeall` in visual mode highlighting the list:
`foo,bar,baz,qux,quux
hello foo how are you 
doing foo bar baz qux
good quux`

will change the text to:

```
hello how are you
doing good
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A safer way is to write a function, check each part of your "list", if there is something needs to be escaped. then do the substitution (removing). A dirty & quick way to do it with your input is with this mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>R :s/,/\|/g<cr>dd:%s/\v<c-r>"<c-h>//g<cr>
```

then in Normal mode, when you go to the line, which contains deletion parts and must be CSV format, press `<leader>R` you will get expected output.

The substitution would fail if that line has regex special chars, like `/`, `*`, `.` or `\` etc.

Comment: What does `dd` stands for in the map you suggested?

Comment: @Jcao02 dd to remove that line. `:h dd`

Comment: Oh sorry, I was trying to execute the command in command mode without mapping and it didn't recognized the `dd`

Comment: @Jcao02 it is a Normal mode mapping, after `<cr>` you were pushed back to normal mode. you can concatenate the first `:s` and `dd` into one with `:s/../../|d`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this one liner should work:

```
:for f in split(getline("."), ",") | execute "%s/" . f | endfor | 0d
```

Note that you'll end up with a lot of trailing spaces.

***edit***

This version of the command above takes care of those pesky trailing spaces (but not the one on line 2 of your sample text):

```
:for f in split(getline("."), ",") | execute "%s/ *" . f | endfor | 0d
```

Result:

```
hello how are you 
doing
good
```